# Syntax error defining typescript promise- how to fix?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to prototype a login authorization to guard some routes in an angualr program, but in the auth-guard.service am getting a TS error at compile time. I can't for the life of me see what is wrong. Here is my code for auth-guard.service:

```
 import { CanActivate,
        ActivatedRoute,
        RouterStateSnapshot,
        ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        Router
    } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router ) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
                state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean  {
                    return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
                        .then(
                            (authenticated: boolean) => {
                                if (authenticated) {
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    this.router.navigate(['/']);
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                        );

    }
}
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
ERROR in src/app/auth-guard.service.ts(19,26): error TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.
```

Here is my auth-service.ts:

```
export class AuthService {
    loggedIn = false;

    isAuthenticated() {
        const promise = new Promise (
            (resolve, reject) =>  {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(this.loggedIn);
                }, 800);
            }
        );
    }

    login() {
        this.loggedIn = true;
    }

    logout() {
        this.loggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

Does isAuthenticated need to define a return value? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.....

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the promise:

```
isAuthenticated() {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) =>  {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(this.loggedIn);
    }, 800);
  });
}
```

You can also define its return type like:

```
isAuthenticated(): Promise<boolean> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: That was it! Many thanks, I'd been staring at this for an hour trying to figure out what I was doing wrong....Most appreciated!

Comment: Glad, I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Need to return the promise in isAuthenticated method.

```
isAuthenticated() {
   const promise = new Promise (
      (resolve, reject) =>  {
         setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(this.loggedIn);
         }, 800);
      }
   );
   return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can just make the method async which will return a Promise and no need for all of the return new Promise()

```
async isAuthenticated() {
        new Promise (
            (resolve, reject) =>  {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    resolve(this.loggedIn);
                }, 800);
            }
        );
    }
```

Sometimes it's more readable to make a wait helper function:

```
async isAuthenticated() {
        await wait(800);
       resolve(this.loggedIn);
    }

async wait(ms: number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms);
   });
}
```